# Azure Web Apps (Linux) needs web.config?

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-2022

I have my Linux Nodejs 16 app running. I published it using an FTPS Publish profile in my Visual Studio 2022. I use PM2 to run the app.

If I'm not mistaken, Azure requires the web.config file that was created in my VS 2022 project for the Nodejs project. Am I right? Why does it want that? It seems more in tune with IIS development than a Linux Nodejs app.